# SignalR Error: signalR(...).starting(...).sending is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm learning basics of implementing SignalR from beside link [Asp.Net Signal MVC4](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc). Just like the tutorial suggested I have implemented a demo application but I am not able to resolve following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: signalR(...).starting(...).sending is not a
>   function

This is what I have tried so far.

**Prerequisite:**

1. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
2. WebAPIDoodle.SignalR

**Hub**

```
namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{        
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send( string name, string message )
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage( name, message );
        }
    }
}
```

**Owin Startup**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup( typeof( SignalRChat.Startup ) )]

namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration( IAppBuilder app )
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Chat()
{
    return View();
}
```

**View (Chat)**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Chat</h2>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var connection = $.connection('/echo');
            console.log(connection);
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

I not able to resolve following error. Is there anything I'm missing here because I have installed all required files and using latest Jquery. I tried using lower version of signalR but still same issue persist.

Here, the snapshot of developer console with list of error.

[image]

**Source of error**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally sorted out the exception the one I have mentioned in my question. Actually I have unnecessarily installed **WebAPIDoodle.SignalR** dll. I have dumped this project and started with a fresh one as soon a the new project setup completes I went to package console manager and one by one updated following dll.

1. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
2. Microsoft.Owin
3. Microsoft.Owin.Security
4. Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Rest process was same as the tutorial suggested creating a owin startup class and a hub class. Doing this much the application worked perfectly just like mentioned in the tutorial. What I do notice was both project signalr autogenereted javascript were different I guess this was because previously I have unnecessarily installed **WebAPIDoodle.SignalR** dll which gave me a different javascript.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 'sending' you should use 'send' because in the file 'charthub.cs' you have declared 'public void send (...)'[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP3JJ.png) [myhub.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vgf9.png)